# Can not separate sample function into two separate function

Tags: function, vbscript

I found [this function](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2389) to encrypt and decrypt strings and this is the sample code from its documentation. In the sample they used encryption and decryption in same block of codes and generated a mediator variable named `bytOut` which is used in both decryption and encryption.

I want to make two separate functions but I don't know how to reuse `bytOut` in second function as it is generated in the first function:

This is the source of sample:

```
<%
sPlain="test"
sPassword="key"

lLength = Len(sPlain)
ReDim bytIn(lLength-1)
For lCount = 1 To lLength
    bytIn(lCount-1) = CByte(AscB(Mid(sPlain, lCount, 1)))
Next

lLength = Len(sPassword)
ReDim bytPassword(lLength-1)
For lCount = 1 To lLength
    bytPassword(lCount-1) = CByte(AscB(Mid(sPassword, lCount, 1)))
Next

'Here the bytOut is generated:
bytOut = EncryptData(bytIn, bytPassword)

sTemp = ""
For lCount = 0 To UBound(bytOut)
    sTemp = sTemp & Right("0" & Hex(bytOut(lCount)), 2)
Next

Response.Write "Encrypted=" & sTemp & "<BR>"

'Here the bytOut is used again
bytClear = DecryptData(bytOut, bytPassword)

lLength = UBound(bytClear) + 1
sTemp = ""
For lCount = 0 To lLength - 1
    sTemp = sTemp & Chr(bytClear(lCount))
Next
Response.Write "Decrypted=" & sTemp
%>
```

I have write these two functions but obviously the second will not work as `bytOut` is not initialized:

MyEncrypt function:

```
Function MyEncrypt(sPlain)
    sPassword = "key"

    lLength = Len(sPlain)
    ReDim bytIn(lLength-1)
    For lCount = 1 To lLength
        bytIn(lCount-1) = CByte(AscB(Mid(sPlain, lCount, 1)))
    Next

    lLength = Len(sPassword)
    ReDim bytPassword(lLength-1)
    For lCount = 1 To lLength
        bytPassword(lCount-1) = CByte(AscB(Mid(sPassword, lCount, 1)))
    Next

    bytOut = EncryptData(bytIn, bytPassword)

    sTemp = ""
    For lCount = 0 To UBound(bytOut)
        sTemp = sTemp & Right("0" & Hex(bytOut(lCount)), 2)
    Next
    MyEncrypt = sTemp
End Function
```

`MyDecrypt` function:

```
Function MyDecrypt(sPlain)
    sPassword = "key"

    lLength = Len(sPassword)
    ReDim bytPassword(lLength-1)
    For lCount = 1 To lLength
        bytPassword(lCount-1) = CByte(AscB(Mid(sPassword, lCount, 1)))
    Next

    'I don't know how to generate bytOut here?

    bytClear = DecryptData(bytOut, bytPassword)

    lLength = UBound(bytClear) + 1
    sTemp = ""
    For lCount = 0 To lLength - 1
        sTemp = sTemp & Chr(bytClear(lCount))
    Next

    MyDecrypt = sTemp
End Function
```

Comment: You need to pass the encrypted data as the parameter of your decryption function. You should also make the key (in this case the password) a parameter to both functions. `MyEncrypt(plaintext, key)` -> ciphertext. `MyDecrypt(ciphertext, key)` -> plaintext.

Comment: Do you mean `bytClear = DecryptData(EncryptedTextHere, myPassword)` ? for example I encrypt the `test` to `93354DFA16DE9C40E4E64CDC1457AF903224D89EF0859A26507FF839E946DC0C` but I get `Type mismatch: 'UBound'` when I decrypt this if I use it as input.

Comment: `MyEncrypt()` returns a hex string. You need to pass that into `MyDecrypt()` and convert it back to a byte array before passing that to `DecryptData()`. Basically you need to do the inverse of the final loop in `MyEncrypt()`.

Comment: Would you please post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your hex string into the function `MyDecrypt()` and convert it back to a byte array:

```
Function MyDecrypt(sCrypt)
    sPassword = "key"

    lLength = Len(sPassword)
    ReDim bytPassword(lLength-1)
    For lCount = 1 To lLength
        bytPassword(lCount-1) = CByte(AscB(Mid(sPassword, lCount, 1)))
    Next

    bLength = Int((Len(sCrypt)+1) / 2) - 1
    ReDim bytOut(bLength)
    For i = 0 To bLength
      bytOut(i) = CByte(Int("&h" & Mid(sCrypt, 2*i+1, 2)))
    Next

    bytClear = DecryptData(bytOut, bytPassword)

    lLength = UBound(bytClear) + 1
    sTemp = ""
    For lCount = 0 To lLength - 1
        sTemp = sTemp & Chr(bytClear(lCount))
    Next

    MyDecrypt = sTemp
End Function
```

I would also recommend passing the password/key as a parameter to both of your functions and refactoring the part that converts it to a byte array into another function that can be used in both `MyEncrypt()` and `MyDecrypt()`.